# @ContentChild is null for DynamicComponentLoader

Tags: angular

I have a side navigation component to be used on many pages. This is not a single-page web app. It is dynamically loaded on a parent component that toggles the menu. ContentChild is used to get a handle on the child component so that it can be toggled by setting @input overlayHidden. The problem is that ContentChild is null.

Run this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZSBg6?p=preview) with the debug console open. Click "Dashboard" from the first page, and then "Toggle Menu" from the second page to see the null pointer.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code.

```
import { Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'side-navigation',
    template: `
    <div id="overlay" [hidden]="overlayHidden">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="menu" class="white-bg active" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help & FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
`
})
export class SideNavigationComponent {
    @Input() overlayHidden: boolean;
}

import { Component, 
    DynamicComponentLoader, 
    Injector, 
    ContentChild,   AfterContentInit 
} from 'angular2/core';

import { Router, RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';
import { SideNavigationComponent } from './side-navigation';

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    template: `
    <side-navigation id="side-navigation"></side-navigation>...
`,
directives: [ 
    RouterLink, 
    SideNavigationComponent ]
})
export class DashboardComponent {
    title = 'Dashboard';
    @ContentChild(SideNavigationComponent)
        sideNavigationComponent: SideNavigationComponent;

    constructor(private _router: Router, 
        private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, 
        private _injector: Injector) {
        this._router = _router;
        this._dcl = _dcl;
        this._injector = _injector;
        this._dcl.loadAsRoot(
            SideNavigationComponent, 
            '#side-navigation', this._injector);
    }

    toggleOverlay() {
        this.overlayHidden = !this.overlayHidden;
        this.sideNavigationComponent.overlayHidden = this.overlayHidden;
    }
}
```

I built a publish/subscribe solution that works (except for an issue with the 'hidden' attribute of the overlay div), but I thought this would be a simpler solution if I could get it to work.

Comment: You should use either `loadNextToLocation` or `loadIntoLocation` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223#issuecomment-193908465

Answer (score 1):

As **Günter** has suggested in his answer about `@ContentChild` and in addition of that you may think about this,
[As discussed with **Günter** - see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ju6zAg?p=preview) 
Sorry I didn't go into deep with your plunker and don't what you want to achieve further. But if you're going to implement `ViewChild` api think about to implement `AfterViewInit` hook as well. And it also works with `DynamicComponentLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues

- LoadAsRoot doesn't invoke change detection

Currently `loadAsRoot()` is only used to bootstrap the root component (`AppComponent`) and inputs aren't supported on the root component.

A workaround is explained in this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6370#issuecomment-193896657

> when using loadAsRoot you need to trigger change detection and manually wire up Inputs, Outputs, Injector, and the component dispose function

```
function onYourComponentDispose() {
}
let el = this.elementRef
let reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne = this.injector;
this.componentLoader.loadAsRoot(YourComponent, this.elementRef, reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne, onYourComponentDispose)
.then((compRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // manually include Inputs
  compRef.instance['myInputValue'] = {res: 'randomDataFromParent'};
  // manually include Outputs
  compRef.instance['myOutputValue'].subscribe(this.parentObserver)
  // trigger change detection
  cmpRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges()
  // always return in a promise
  return compRef
});
```

This comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7453#issuecomment-193138577 also has a link to a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tcgbI2?p=preview) example demonstrating the workaround

- DynamicComponentLoader can't be used in `constructor()`. This code should should be moved to `ngAfterViewInit()`:

  this._dcl.loadAsRoot(
          SideNavigationComponent, 
          '#side-navigation', this._injector);
- as @Miconyks pointed out `@ViewChild()` should be used instead of `@ContentChild()`. `@ContentChild()` is for content passed to `<ng-content>`

Comment: @Steve, @Günter - Can't we use `ViewChild` instead of `ContentChild` for this use-case?

Comment: You are right. I also think it should be `ViewChild` instead.