# Angular 2 dynamic loaded component, events not firing back?

Tags: typescript, angular

I used Angular2 Dynamic Component Loader. All is working well.

My dynamically loaded component emits events, but I can't catch it anywhere.

Parent code:

```
this.dcl.loadAsRoot(SomeComponent, "#dynamiccomponenthere", this.injector)
```

Parent template:

```
<div id="dynamiccomponenthere" (somecustomevent)="someFunc()"></div>
```

Child:

```
...
this.somecustomevent.emit(data)
...
```

***SOLUTION: (thx Gunther) ***

```
cmp.instance['somecustomevent'].subscribe(ev => {
    this.consoleLog(ev) // run function in parent!
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- LoadAsRoot doesn't invoke change detection

Currently `loadAsRoot()` is only used to bootstrap the root component (`AppComponent`) and inputs aren't supported on the root component.

A workaround is explained in this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6370#issuecomment-193896657

> when using loadAsRoot you need to trigger change detection and manually wire up Inputs, Outputs, Injector, and the component dispose function

```
function onYourComponentDispose() {
}
let el = this.elementRef
let reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne = this.injector;
this.componentLoader.loadAsRoot(YourComponent, this.elementRef, reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne, onYourComponentDispose)
.then((compRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // manually include Inputs
  compRef.instance['myInputValue'] = {res: 'randomDataFromParent'};
  // manually include Outputs
  compRef.instance['myOutputValue'].subscribe(this.parentObserver)
  // trigger change detection
  cmpRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges()
  // always return in a promise
  return compRef
});
```

See also [@ContentChild is null for DynamicComponentLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972753/contentchild-is-null-for-dynamiccomponentloader/35972767#35972767)

Comment: See the line with `myOutputValue`. This is an example how listening to events is set up for components added with `loadAsRoot()`.

Comment: In this example. What is `this.parentObserver` suppose to be? Where does parentObserver come from?

Comment: Never mind.. I figured it out. `parentObserver` in my case it was an internal function.. IE `private someFunction(){ }`