# Interpolation binding doesn't work

Tags: angular

I'm loading a component dynamically via **loadAsRoot**
After I load the component, the component is loaded in the UI but the bounded interpolated data isn't loaded even though it's properties have values.

```
var componentLoadPromise = this._componentLoader.loadAsRoot(MyComponent, "#placeholder", this._injector);

 return componentLoadPromise.then(myComp=> {
          return new Promise<boolean>(resolve =>{ 
          myComp["_hostElement"]["component"]["display"](compOptions, resolve);      
          });
    });
enter code here
```

**Component.ts**

```
  // bounded properties
  public  content: string;
  public  title: string;


 public display(dialogOptions: IDialogParams, resolve: (boolean) => any){
    document.onkeyup = null;
    this._resolveAction = resolve;
    this.setUpElements();
    // here my bounded view properties are populated
    this.populateViewProperties(dialogOptions);

    this.wireEvents();
    this._confirmElement.style.display = "block";    
 }
```

Comment: Please share your code. Html + Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated. Use instead `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`

`DynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot()` is only supposed to be used by `bootstrap()` for the root component and doesn't do any change detection by default. You would need to wire up change detection manually to make it work.

See also

- [@ContentChild is null for DynamicComponentLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972753/contentchild-is-null-for-dynamiccomponentloader/35972767#35972767)
- [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: I don't see a lot of documentation on 
I have a global service that needs to load dynamically a component when it is called.
How do I get a ref to ViewContainerRef?

Comment: You can inject it `constructor(ref:ViewContainerRef)` then you get the one from the component where you inject it or you can use `@ViewChild(ComponentTypeOrTemplateVariableName, {read: ViewContainerRef}) ref:ViewContainerRef;`. Components added this way are added as sibling of the element the `ViewContainerRef` is from.

Comment: Also, how do you know that it's deprecated? where is the reference to that?

Comment: It was mentioned many times in GitHub issues by Angular team members since months. I haven't seen it added to the `DynamicComponentLoader` to make it official myself though.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468